# I am facing an issue while using ejs-mate. The error is in <% layout("path") %>. The path is correct But does not work

Tags: javascript, express, ejs, web-development-server, templating-engine

**Error Msg :-**

```
no such file or directory, open 'D:\Web Projects\major\views\listings\layouts\boilerplate.ejs'
```

I have tried a lot but in a result I got the error again and again.I have changed the syntax and even I have copied the same code and from the npm website. I have used `app.engine("ejs",ejsMate)` and as well I have set the view engine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As the Community Bot says, provide more information so we can understand better where the issue might be coming from, like code that calls that boilerplate, code that sets the view engine and engine, project structure, etc.
The only thing I can suggest, since the path seems good, is to check if you've set the engine of ejs to ejs-mate with `engine = require('ejs-mate'); app.engine('ejs', engine);`